# Routing problems in express (Headers already set)

Tags: node.js, express

Not consistently, but sometimes I'm receiving a `Can't set headers after they are sent` error. Usually when I'm trying to load many images from the database at the same time.

Express seems to be sending a 404 before the router get function is even called. Here is the router function:

```
router.get('/:imageId', formparser, function (req, res) {
  imageStorage.fetch(req.params.imageId).then(function (img) {
    console.log(res._headerSent);
    if (img) {
      res.contentType(img.contentType);
      res.send(img.data);
    } else
      res.status(404).send();
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Any idea what could be the cause?

*More Info:* I think there might be something tricky with the wiring I failed to implement. I'm using 5 different `Router`s, and they're added to the `express` app like so:

```
app.use('/images', require('./routes/imageroutes'));
app.use('/course', require('./routes/courseroutes'));
app.use('/user', require('./routes/userroutes'));
app.use('/class', require('./routes/classroutes'));
app.use('/responses', require('./routes/responsesroutes'));
```

pointers would be appreciated.

The `formparser.js` middleware:

```
'use strict';

const formidable = require('formidable');

function parse(opts) {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.multiples = true;
  Object.assign(form, opts);

  return (req, res, next) => {
    var fields = {};
    var files = {};
    form.parse(req, function (err, _fields, files) { fields = _fields; });
    form.onPart = function (part) {
      if (!part.filename) {
        // let formidable handle all non-file parts 
        form.handlePart(part);
      } else {
        var file = { mime: part.mime, filename: part.filename, buffer: null };
        var chunks = [];
        part.on('data', function (chunk) {
          chunks.push(chunk);
        });
        part.on('end', function () {
          file.buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks); // merge all the chunks to a single buffer
          chunks = null;
        })
        files[part.name] = file;
      }
    };
    form.on('end', function () {
      Object.assign(req, { fields, files });
      next();
    });
  };
}

module.exports = parse;
exports.parse = parse; // backword compatibility
```

Comment: In all likelihood, it's happening in your middleware. It's sending an error (or anything), and continuing to your route where you try to send something again and it throws the error.

Comment: I thought so, but I don't think any of the middlewares I use could throw a 404: I use `cookie-session` and `express-formidable` (formparser here)

Comment: under the `router.get`, do you have a `module.exports = router;`?

Comment: Can you show us your middleware "formparser" ?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon definitely. the router works - but when two request happen in parallel, one of them fails (404 + error)

Comment: You have some asynchronous function somewhere that is either calling `next()` or its using `res` object after you have called `.send()`

Comment: Maybe you pass many time on form.on('end') event ?

Comment: you should call the midleware as a function i gues `router.get('/:imageId', formparser(), function (req, res) {`....

Comment: @Sparw thank you very much Spraw it seems to be that. Also, thank you for everyone for pointing me to the middleware. (including @alizahid)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `express-formidable` package. The same behaviour was documented in [Issue #6 of express-formidable on GitHub](https://github.com/utatti/express-formidable/issues/6).

Many thanks to those who pointed me in the right direction.